# Scrapy: Requesting a different html inside parse()

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to request a new HTML while inside parse?

My code currently is reading HTML links in a CSV file and then putting all links on it in the `start_urls` list.

What I want to happen is when it gets a link on `start_urls`, parses it, loops on all pages until it satisfies a condition inside the loop.  Breaks the entire loop and continue parsing the next item on the `start_urls` list

```
with open('.\scrappy_demo.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    #Open CSV File here
    linkreader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel)
    for row in linkreader:
        start_url.append(str(row)[2:-2]+"/search?page=1")
        i += 1

class demo(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    def parse1(self, response):
        return response

    def parse(self, response):
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        ENDLOOP = False
        ...
        while(next_page <> current_page and not ENDLOOP):
                entry_list = response.css('.entry__row-inner-wrap').extract()

                while (i < len(entry_list) and not ENDLOOP):
                        [Doing some css,xpath filtering here]
                        if([Some Condition here]):
                                [Doing some file write here]
                                ENDLOOP = True
                        i += 1

                j += 1
                nextPage = url_redir[:-1]+str(j+1)
                body = Request(nextPage, callback=self.parse1)
                response2 = HtmlResponse(nextPage, body=body)
```

On the last 2 lines, I'm trying to request a new html but with a +1 increment on the page number. But when the code runs, it doesn't return the html code of the request. What am I missing here?

Note: I tried checking the values of body and response2 by printing it but it looks like `body.body` is empty and the callback doesn't get executed

Note2: First time using scrappy

Note3: I know that code fails on 2 digit page number, but nvm that for now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this. Note that while statements were replaced and code looks much nicer. Yo may want to do a recursive algorithm to resolve this, but I'm not sure what exactly you want to acomplish. The following code is not tested.

```
    ...
    for url in  start_urls:
        entry_list = response.css('.entry__row-inner-wrap').extract()

        for innerurl in entry_list:
                [Doing some css, xpath filtering here]
                if([Some Condition here]):
                        [Doing some file write here]
                        ENDLOOP = True

        body = Request(nextPage, callback=self.parse1)
        response2 = HtmlResponse(url, body=body)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this problem is not about iterators and loops. I managed to fix it though by learning how to use 'yield' in python

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it after a 4 hours.

I learned how to use Scrapy's "self.make_requests_from_url" and `yield` command in python.

Fixed code:

```
with open('C:\Users\MDuh\Desktop\scrape\scrappy_demo.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
linkreader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel)
for row in linkreader:
    start_url.append(str(row)[2:-2]+"/search?page=1")
    i += 1

def parse(self, response):
        i = 0;
        ENDLOOP = False
        ...
        [Pagination CSS/XPATH filtering here]
        next_page = int(pagination_response[pagination_parse:pagination_response[pagination_parse:].find('"')+pagination_parse])
        current_page = int(str(response.url)[-((len(str(response.url)))-(str(response.url).find('?page='))-6):])

        giveaway_list = response.css('.giveaway__row-inner-wrap').extract()
        while (i < len(giveaway_list) and not ENDLOOP):
                if([CONDITION HERE]):
                    [FILE WRITE HERE]
                    ENDLOOP = True
                    raise StopIteration
                i += 1

        if(next_page <> current_page and not ENDLOOP):
           yield self.make_requests_from_url(url_redir[:-(len(url_redir)-url_redir.find("page=")-5)]+str(next_page))

        base_url[:-(len(base_url)-base_url.find("/search?page="))]
```